# Retrieve featured image as object

Tags: post-thumbnails

I want to retrieve the featured image of a post as an object (`array`) in order to have all image sizes available.

The `get_the_post_thumbnail()` function doesn't do this, any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First get the registered image sizes and the featured image attachment id:

```
$sizes = get_intermediate_image_sizes();
$post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
```

Loop through the registered sizes and create an array:

```
$images = array();
foreach ( $sizes as $size ) {
    $images[] = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_thumbnail_id, $size );
}
```

Combined as a function to place inside functions.php:

```
function get_all_image_sizes($attachment_id = 0) {
    $sizes = get_intermediate_image_sizes();
    if(!$attachment_id) $attachment_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();

    $images = array();
    foreach ( $sizes as $size ) {
        $images[] = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size );
    }

    return $images;
}
```

Usage:

```
$featured_image_sizes = get_all_image_sizes();
```

Comment: Thanks passatgt. So there is no easier way to retrieve an object from the featured image? They really should implement it as a core function.

Comment: Well, usually you only need 1 size. You can use Advanced Custom Fields with the image field which will retrieve a full array with all sizes, but if you place the function i wrote inside your functions.php, its not that complicated.

Comment: The reason I want all sizes is because I'm using Picturefill to adhere to responsive images. WP really needs to address this within the system. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

This is old, but the above answer isn't quite complete. To properly get all image sizes with all of the image attributes, you'd need to grab the attachment object as well.

Something like this:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    $thumb = array();
    $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();

    // first grab all of the info on the image... title/description/alt/etc.
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'include' => $thumb_id
    );
    $thumbs = get_posts( $args );
    if ( $thumbs ) {
        // now create the new array
        $thumb['title'] = $thumbs[0]->post_title;
        $thumb['description'] = $thumbs[0]->post_content;
        $thumb['caption'] = $thumbs[0]->post_excerpt;
        $thumb['alt'] = get_post_meta( $thumb_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true );
        $thumb['sizes'] = array(
            'full' => wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumb_id, 'full', false )
        );
        // add the additional image sizes
        foreach ( get_intermediate_image_sizes() as $size ) {
            $thumb['sizes'][$size] = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumb_id, $size, false );
        }
    } // end if

    // display the 'custom-size' image
    echo '<img src="' . $thumb['sizes']['custom-size'][0] . '" alt="' . $thumb['alt'] . '" title="' . $thumb['title'] . '" width="' . $thumb['sizes']['custom-size'][1] . '" height="' . $thumb['sizes']['custom-size'][2] . '" />';
} // end if
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok another update to this after some years. I presume that you managed by now ;). But for those who would like to do this and return something that is consistent with - let's say - ACF image objects and allows you to easily populate sourcesets. You could do something like this in functions.php:

```
function get_all_image_sizes($attachment_id = 0) {
  $sizes = get_intermediate_image_sizes();
  if(!$attachment_id) $attachment_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();

  $images = array();
  foreach ( $sizes as $size ) {
    $images[$size] = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size )[0];
  }
  $imageObject = array(
    'sizes' => $images
  );

  return $imageObject;
}
```

And then you can use it like this

```
   $thumbID = get_post_thumbnail_id();
   $image = get_all_image_sizes($thumbID);
   $html = '<img src="'. $image['sizes']['large'] .'" alt="">';
```